# Declare an object even before that class is created 

Tags: c++, class, object, instantiation

Is there anyway to declare an object of a class before the class is created in C++?  I ask because I am trying to use two classes, the first needs to have an instance of the second class within it, but the second class also contains an instance of the first class.  I realize that you may think I might get into an infinite loop, but I actually need to create and instance of the second class before the first class.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't do something like this:

```
class A {
    B b;
};
class B {
    A a;
};
```

The most obvious problem is the compiler doesn't know how to large it needs to make class A, because the size of B depends on the size of A!

You can, however, do this:

```
class B; // this is a "forward declaration"
class A {
    B *b;
};
class B {
    A a;
};
```

Declaring class B as a forward declaration allows you to use pointers (and references) to that class without yet having the whole class definition.

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare an instance of an undefined class but you can declare a **pointer** to one:

```
class A;  // Declare that we have a class A without defining it yet.

class B
{
public:
    A *itemA;
};

class A
{
public:
    B *itemB;
};
```

Comment: ...or a reference to one: MyClass & rMyObject;

Answer (score 2):

There's [an elegant solution](http://acius2.blogspot.com/2007/11/breaking-return-by-value-recursive.html) using templates.

> ```
> template< int T > class BaseTemplate {};
> typedef BaseTemplate< 0 > A;
> typedef BaseTemplate< 1 > B;
> // A
> template<> class BaseTemplate< 0 >
> {
> public:
>    BaseTemplate() {} // A constructor
>    B getB();
> }
>
> // B
> template<> class BaseTemplate< 1 >
> {
> public:
>    BaseTemplate() {} // B constructor
>    A getA();
> }
>
> inline B A::getB() { return A(); }
> inline A B::getA() { return B(); }
> ```
>
> This code will work! So, why does it
>   work? The reason has to do with how
>   templates are compiled. Templates
>   delay the creation of function
>   signatures until you actually use the
>   template somewhere. This means that
>   neither getA() nor getB() will have
>   their signatures analyzed until after
>   both classes A and B have already been
>   fully declared. That's the magic of
>   this method.

Comment: Interesting (although it contains several typos).  But the 'getA' and 'getB' are really factories: they return new instances (by value).  An instance of A does not have-a B nor does an instance of B have-an A.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you want: The first class contains the second class, but the second class (that is to be created first) just has a reference to the first class?

Comment: I am actually trying to do the reverse, where the first class references the second class and the second class contains an instances of the first class.

Answer (score 0):

This is called cross reference. See [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread97195.html) an example.